# What is the scope of the special case `FLAG ??` override in procmail?

Tags: procmail

`man procmailrc` says:

> **variablename ??**  Match the remainder of this condition against the value of this environment variable (which cannot be a pseudo variable).  A special case is if **variablename** is equal to `B`, `H`, `HB` or `BH`; this merely overrides the default header/body search area defined by the initial flags on this recipe.

When using the `??` operator for the *special case* mentioned, does the "override" of the default flags persist only for this condition or for the entire rest of the recipe?

For example, if I specify

```
:0 H
* ^To:.*recipient
* B ?? tribbles
* ^From:.*space
```

will the `From` condition be tried against the `B`ody because of the preceding line's override, or do the flags revert to their initial condition (`H`) after the override line ends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The override persists only for the condition in which it is defined.  Here's a slightly-altered experiment to demonstrate:

**pm-test.rc**

```
:0 H
* ^To:.*recipient
* B ?? tribbles
* space
mailbox
```

**test-mail.txt**

```
From: space-alert@storage.com
To: recipient@local.net

Your storage locker is overflowing with
tribbles.  Please clean it out.
```

Note that the word "space" appears only in the headers of the above message.

**test-mail2.txt**

```
From: alert@star.fleet
To: recipient@local.net

We're having some trouble with
tribbles at our space station.
```

Note that the word "space" appears only in the body of the above message.

---

If the `B` override does *not* expire at the end of its condition, `pm-test.rc` should **succeed** on the second message because "tribbles" is in the body and "space" is (only) in the body.

```
% procmail VERBOSE=on DEFAULT=/dev/null MAILDIR=/tmp pm-test.rc < test-mail2.txt

procmail: Match on "^To:.*recipient"
procmail: Match on "tribbles"
procmail: No match on "space"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/dev/null"
```

The recipe does **not** succeed.

Conversely, if the `B` override *does* expire at the end of its condition, `pm-test.rc` should **succeed** on the first message because "tribbles" is in the body and "space" is (only) in the headers.

```
% procmail VERBOSE=on DEFAULT=/dev/null MAILDIR=/tmp pm-test.rc < test-mail.txt

procmail: Match on "^To:.*recipient"
procmail: Match on "tribbles"
procmail: Match on "space"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=mailbox"
```

The recipe does **succeed**.

So, conditions after the `B` override are unaffected by said override. 
 They go back to using the recipe's original flags (`H`).

Comment: Indeed, think of it as if `$H` was a shell variable which contains the message's headers, and `$B` its body, and `$HB` (as well as `$BH`) their concatenation.